# How to write fulfillment code from an IDE instead of the inline editor?

Tags: javascript, python, agent, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I was wondering if it is possible to use a preferred IDE rather than code your fulfillment functions in the provided in-line editor? If so, can anyone provide steps/links to set up the communication between an IDE and the designated Agent?

P.S. I've already tried using the Dialogflow API, and being that I don't want to implement my agent into a website, it was no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you can use the below step to connect your server for Dialogflow fulfillment.

1. Create your server in preferred language (I have used NodeJS/Express)
2. when you get this running on localhost, expose it so that dialogflow can connect to your server.
3. Use ngrok for proxy expose.
4. Add fulfillment details in Dialogflow.
5. Write your code locally.

**app.js**

```
const app = express();
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')))
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("online"));
app.post("/dialogflow", express.json(), (req, res) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set("Default Welcome Intent", welcome);
    intentMap.set("Exit Intent", exit);
});
function exit(agent){}
function welcome(agent){}
```

Run Ngrok and get the public link
[image: run ngrok get the public link]

Add these server details in Dialogflow fulfillment
[image]

**Note:** This is only for local development later you can add a real production server url where your fulfillment will be running.

Comment: Awesome! So if I use this code in Pycharm using Python, will it still work, or does it have to be translated from Node.js/express?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in python as well with the same process.

Comment: Ok, and last thing. In order to code fulfillment linking to various API’s, would I be able to do so in the python language or is it only able to be done in JavaScript?

Comment: yes, you can do it in python as well. You have to check the fulfillment library. and any other 3rd party API like weather etc. You can call from your own intent handler inside your python code.